# Handlebars JS -- Get Data from the Third (Last) Element of an Array

Tags: jquery, json, handlebars.js, spotify

I have a JSON data object that is a result of requesting a list of albums from the Spotify API. The data object contains an array of album objects. The array is called "items". Each object has an array of 3 images and that array is called "images"

I need to extract the URL from the third image in the array and insert it into my html something like this:

```
<img src="{{url}}"/>
```

Here is the template I'm using:

```
{{#each items}}
  <div>
    <h2>{{name}}</h2>
    {{#each images}}
      {{#getSmallImage @index}}
        <img src="{{url}}"/>
      {{/getSmallImage}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

I've registered the following helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("getSmallImage", function (index, options) {
    return index == 2;
});
```

Instead of printing the desired **img** element, the script simply prints the word "true."

Horribly wrong, I know.

I've seen similar posts on SO but need help with this specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handlebars has a `@last` variable within an each block. The [documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/reference.html#data-last) says it is a bool that will be true for the last step of the iteration. So you could change your template to the following:

```
{{#each items}}
    <div>
        <h2>{{name}}</h2>
        {{#each images}}
            {{#if @last}}
                <img src="{{url}}"/>
            {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks, 76484, that's exactly what I needed. I had also correctly figured out how to use the helper function.